# Why there is an error when i try to create a matrix in C using file dimension as row and columns?

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a matrix using file dimensions, they are 10kb files. I'm calculating the file dimension using this function

```
long calculateDim(char *path) {
FILE *fd= fopen(path,"r+");
fseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
long dim= ftell(fd);
fclose(fd);
return dim;
}
```

The matrix code:

```
long dim1=calculateDim(path1);
long dim2=calculateDim(path2);
long matrix[dim1 + 1][dim2 + 1];
```

The error is :

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

In particular it return a Segmentation Fault in the line of the matrix creation

Comment: How big are `dim1` and `dim2`?  How many bytes do you then expect `matrix` will take up?  Will an object of that size fit on your stack? (or should you be using dynamic memory?)

Comment: dim1 and dim2 are 10038, that is the files dimension in bytes. I will also need to use larger files. Matrix in that case will be 10038*10038 and it could be fit in the stack

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> dim1 and dim2 are 10038, that is the files dimension in bytes. I will also need to use larger files. Matrix in that case will be 10038*10038 and it could be fit in the stack

If your matrix is to have over 100 million elements, each taking up 8 bytes, then the matrix is to take a bit shy of 800 MB of storage.

You claim this will fit on the stack.  ***Why?***
The typical stack size for most apps is between 1 and 4 MB.
I doubt very much that 800 MB will fit on the stack.